# QGIS Print Composer: Is it possible to label only select coordinates?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, design

On my map frame I want to have the first and last coordinate labels styled differently than the other coordinates (see picture).

[image]

I have created two separate grids for the different styles and now want to define which labels to show and which to hide. I have tried to add a custom expression under **Draw Coordinates**:

`if(@grid_number IN ('4531000','4528000'),'disabled','all')`

But, somewhat expectedly, this was unsuccessful.
Is there any way to define which coordinate labels to show (or is there another solution to my problem) within QGIS or do I need to do this in post processing with an external graphics program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an expression to get the corner coordinates and the internal coordinates. Look at https://kartoza.com/blog/uncategorised/data-defined-settings-for-grid-placements-in-qgis-312

Comment: This is great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this in QGIS through quite the ugly hack:

1. create 4 different grids for the map:
   For X & Y axis respectively: One style for the corner coordinates,
   **set the X or Y interval to match the extent of the corner grid marks**, another style for the shortened coordinates in between.
2. Duplicate the main map.
3. For the top map activate the grids with the corner coordinates & deactivate the other grids
4. For the bottom map do the opposite: activate the shortened coordinates and deactivate the corner coordinates.
5. Draw 4 white rectangles covering the corner coordinates and place them inbetween the two maps.

As I said, it is not pretty, but it works ;)